# Mediawiki does not run for the first time

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, mediawiki

I'm trying to install Mediawiki 1.22.6 into a subdirectory `/wiki/` of apache document root directory, which contains some other directories. When I try to open http://example.com/wiki or http://example.com/wiki/index.php for the very first time to generate LocalSettings.php, the script is not run; instead, a *part* of it is printed:

> bar(), etc etc) which throw parse errors in # PHP 4. Setup.php and ObjectCache.php have structures invalid in PHP 5.0 and # 5.1, respectively. if ( !function_exists( 'version_compare' ) || version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3.2' ) < 0 ) { // We need to use dirname( **FILE** ) here cause **DIR** is PHP5.3+ require dirname( **FILE** ) . '/includes/PHPVersionError.php'; wfPHPVersionError( 'index.php' ); } # Initialise common code. This gives us access to GlobalFunctions, the # AutoLoader, and the globals $wgRequest, $wgOut, $wgUser, $wgLang and # $wgContLang, amongst others; it does *not* load $wgTitle require **DIR** . '/includes/WebStart.php'; $mediaWiki = new MediaWiki(); $mediaWiki->run();

Running the script with `php -f index.php` produces the expected output.

There are no aliases or rewrite rules; mod_php seems to be enabled — Mediawiki works if installed as document root. In current install the document root is a symlink.

Virtual host is configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/hell/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/hell/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        IndexOptions +ShowForbidden
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/hell/public_html/private>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Access"
        AuthUserFile /home/hell/apasswords
        Require user satan
    </Directory>
#   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
#   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
#       AllowOverride None
#       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#       Order allow,deny
#       Allow from all
#   </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So there is no special configuration for Mediawiki.

Comment: Is PHP enabled on the server?  Does serving/accessing a simple like `file.php` with `<?php
echo "php enabled";?>` as its contents work?

Comment: It's weird. PHP is apparently enabled (`php5.conf` and `php5.load` are in `mods-enabled`). If the document root is a subdirectory of some user's home directory, both `file.php` and Mediawiki's `index.php` work. If it is a symlink form some user's home directory to a directory located in `/storage/`, neither of them works. If the document root points directly to a directory in `/storage/`, `file.php` works but not Mediawiki.

Comment: Actually no, they all work. It could have been a cache quirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when userdir is enabled, php is disabled for `/home/*/public_html` directories. Renaming `public_html` to something else helped.

Comment: So it works now?  Or the test file works in some locations and not others but MW doesn't work?  There's a lot of moving parts in your setup it seems and many Apache Directives for controlling behaviors and handling of content in one Location (FileSystem or Virtual) or another; with or without symlinks; etc.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I don't actually need to move the files, it was just for test.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum PHP version required for `Mediawiki 1.22.6` is `5.3.2`. You don't show the full output in your question, but it looks like the message you are getting is actually the contents of Mediawiki's main index file. The simplest explanation is that you don't have an Apache handler (*e.g.* `AddHandler`) configured to properly serve `.php` files, so the `index.php` file is being served as text.

Even if PHP is enabled (usually with a configuration directive like `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in your main `httpd.conf` or included in some way from a separate file or directory) you may still need to enable it inside your `VirtualHost` container with a directive like:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Since it's more secure to serve `.php` files using PHP (we don't want their contents to be readable if they include information that should not be public), a handler for `.php` files should be enabled for the whole server. If you are serving PHP files using a `CGI` or `FCGI` process additional configuration steps might be required.

**A more complicated explanation**

You may have multiple versions of PHP installed. Perhaps your version of `mod_php` was compiled against an older version of the PHP libraries, whereas the command line version (sometimes installed separately via a package like `php-cli`) is linked against a more up to date set of libraries and thus works properly.

Locate the libraries associated with mod_php (substitute your package management tool commands as appropriate):

```
% pkg info -a | grep mod_php
mod_php5-5.4.28,1              PHP Scripting Language
% pkg info -l mod_php5-5.4.28,1
mod_php5-5.4.28,1:
    /usr/local/libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
    /usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php5-5.4.28,1/LICENSE
    /usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php5-5.4.28,1/PHP301
    /usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php5-5.4.28,1/catalog.mk
```

or

```
% locate libphp5.so
/usr/local/libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
% pkg which /usr/local/libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
```

If you are sure the version of PHP you have installed is correct and your server is set up to handle `.php` properly but you are still having problems, then debugging using Apache debug levels and log files is your next step.

Comment: Yes, it turns out Apache sends the script's content. It's being displayed like this because of the way Firefox parses it.

Comment: Then most likely you need to enable PHP for your server and/or VirtualHost.